# MongoDB TextScore

Tags: mongodb, search, text

I m new to MongoDB, for me I need to search the name " Raja Sekar " from name field in the database,

I have indexed it. But my condition is search term should match 75 percent of similar records.

Can you please help me with this

```
db.customers.find(
  { $text: { $search: "raja sekar kumar" } }, 
  { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } 
).sort({ score: { $meta: "textScore" } })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match on [text score](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/#match-on-text-score).

```
db.customers.aggregate(
   [
     { $match: { $text: { $search: "raja sekar kumar" } } },
     { $project: { _id: 0, score: { $meta: "textScore" } } },
     { $match: { score: { $gt: 0.75 } } }
   ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am new to MongoDB, Is this correct if suppose i want 80 percent of the match record means can I use 0.80. Please suggest me

Comment: You're welcome. No, percentage scores are different from generated weighted score. Here is the [discussion](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/lucene/ScoresAsPercentages) why percentage scores are not reliable.

Comment: Yeah, I understood but my requirement is to find 80 percent of the match record. Here what i need to do ?